# Azure Synapse Analytics SQL Query with Variables

Tags: sql, variables, google-bigquery, azure-synapse

I have an Azure Synapse Analytics Pipeline with Copy Activity. The Activity pulls data from a Google BigQuery data source. The data is pulled upon a few criteria including a beginning and end date. Here is the problematic query in the Copy Activity's 'Query' section :

```
 @concat('SELECT LogObject FROM `xxxx.yyyy.LogMetric` WHERE
 SourceApplication = '185' AND EventType = 'Request'  AND  TIMESTAMP(EventTime) BETWEEN  
 ','''', variables('begin_date'),'''', ' AND ', '''', variables('end_date'),'''' )
```

Upon running above query, I get an error like this:

```
'Type=System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException,Message=ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][BigQuery] (70) Invalid query: Syntax error: Expected end of input but got \"@\" at [1:1],Source=Microsoft ODBC Driver for Google BigQuery
```

**Update 1** If I don't use @concat and do like:

```
SELECT LogObject FROM LogMetric WHERE TIMESTAMP(EventTime) BETWEEN 
TIMESTAMP(@variables('begin_date') AND 
TIMESTAMP(@variables('end_date'));
```

Then I get error:

```
Function call cannot be applied to this expression. Function calls require a path, e.g. a.b.c()
```

If I run a simpler query for testing, that works:

```
SELECT LogObject FROM `xxxx.yyyy.LogMetric` WHERE
SourceApplication = '185' AND EventType = 'Request' LIMIT 5;'
```

But I need to be able to use the two variables `begin_date` and `end_date`.

When the datasource in the Copy Activity was SQL Server, I was able to make that work fine; the difference was that in case of SQL Server, the non-date filters were numeric, such as:

```
@concat('Select LogObject from MyTable where AppRequestKeyId=185 and EventType=1 AND CAST 
(LogDate AS datetime2) BETWEEN  ','''', variables('begin_date'),'''', ' AND ', '''', 
variables('end_date'),'''' )
```

How can I make my query to work for Google BigQuery as well which would include the variables?

Comment: Have you tried FORMAT_TIMESTAMP instead of TIMESTAMP? How about you try using PARSE_TIMESTAMP? Not sure about the error message, but looks to me the comparison can yield incompatible types (TIMESTAMP is a type but not necessarily one matching the variables type).

Comment: I have tried the TIMESTAMP() directly in Google Cloud using something like 'BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2023-06-19') AND TIMESTAMP('2023-06-20')' and no issues. I think my problem is composing the string for the query with variables.

Comment: Gotcha; you're on the right track then :) it must be something related to the expression. Your original query looks incorrect by '185, as the apostrophe would signal the end of the first value to concatenate (it also needs escaping).

Comment: @hector-j-rivas Thank you. Please also see Update 1 for an alternate query. I feel like getting closer using that instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your updated query is that you are using the  `@`  symbol inside the  `TIMESTAMP`  function to reference the values of the  `begin_date`  and  `end_date`  variables. This is not the correct syntax for referencing variables.

To reference variables in Azure Synapse Analytics, you should use the following syntax:  `@{variables('variable_name')}`. Note that the variable name should be enclosed in single quotes, and the entire expression should be wrapped within **curly braces `@{....}`**.

Here is the corrected query:

```
SELECT LogObject FROM LogMetric WHERE TIMESTAMP(EventTime) BETWEEN 
TIMESTAMP('@{variables('begin_date')}') AND 
TIMESTAMP('@{variables('end_date')}')
```

**Reference**: MS document on [expressions in ADF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#expressions)

Comment: Hi, Looks promising. But now I get an error:  '@variables('begin_date')'. But if I change to BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('''2023-06-19''') AND TIMESTAMP('''2023-06-20'''); then it works.

Comment: Oh, never mind. I had some extra single quotes. Your Answer works. Thank you so much!!